# mod_rewrite, /index.php?p=test to /test

Tags: mod-rewrite

i'm trying to set up a very simple rule in .htaccess file in order to rewrite this kind of url: www.domain.com/index.php?page=test to this: www.domain.com/test

I'm newbie to mod_rewrite, and so far, i came to this rule

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

but it doesn't work.

Any help?
Thanks a lot

Comment: is this a typo: "index.php?$1"? this should be "index.php?page=$1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost right, you just forgot the `page=`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Now note that this rule does the exact opposite: It rewrites requests of paths like `/test` internally to `/index.php?page=test` and *not* vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1.php [NC,L]
```

This also ensures your URL can only contain letters, numbers, dashes and underscores.

Altough, on a sidenote, I'd recommend you to have separate files for each page and including a header.php and a footer.php in those...

Comment: What's the purpose of FollowSymLinks here?

Comment: Just to make sure that URL rewriting is active. Most of the time it is, but sometimes it isn't. No harm having it anyway.